# apache custom-log format with regex expression

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, mod-jk

We have apache webserver as "entry" for incoming traffic it then delegates to tomcats with mod_jk.

We want to log the HTTP digest username, sample header:

```
Authorization: Digest username="Mufasa",
                     realm="testrealm@host.com",
                     nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093",
                     ...
```

Unfortunately using the '%u' doesn't work [as described](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html). My guess is as we authenticate on tomcat side (apache delegates calls to tomcat with mod_jk) the own logging facility of apache doesn't know how to access the digest-username (because own auth module is bypassed).

To workaround this: Is there a custom log-format expression with regex matching for, e.g. telling to extract **username="(.*?)"** from 'Authorization' header and push to logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SetEnvIf Authorization username="([^"]+)" digest_username=$1
LogFormat "%h %l %{digest_username}e %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined_with_user
CustomLog /path/to/log combined_with_user
```

Haven't tested, so not sure if Apache is going to choke on the quotes in the `SetEnvIf` (they may need escaped) - but this should be pretty close.

Comment: thanks, this one looks promising. will accept answer when I tried out on our servers.